# Writing a program that fills an array of 100 integers from 1 to 100

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

So im having a minor problem with this. I just dont know if im doing it correctly. The question is vague. (to me) Was wondering if I could get some help because ive been at this simple problem in my book for 2 hours now and its ticking me off! Thanks in advance :)

"Write a program that populates "fills" an array of 100 integer elements with the numbers from 1 to 100 and then outputs the numbers in the array."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int size = 301;
int N, I, k;
int score[size];
srand(time(0));


cout   << setprecision(2)
       << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
       << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

//1)Get # of bowlers ..............................................................
      cout << "Enter number of bowlers? (Must be between 1 and 301) ";
      cin >> N;
      while (N<1||N>size)
{
      cout << "\nError!! Must be between 1 and 301!! ";
      cin >> N;
}
//2) and 5)  Get scores ............................................................
for(I = 0; I<N; I++)
{
//cout << "\nEnter score for bowler # " << I + 1 << " ";
//cin >> score[I];
score[I]=rand()%301;

for(k=0; k<I; k++)
{
    if(score[k]==score[I])
    {
        I--;
        break;
    }

}
}

//3)Get Sum/Avg .....................................................................
int sum = 0;
float avg;
for(I = 0; I<N; I++)
{
sum += score [I];

}

avg = float(sum)/N;




//4) Output scores, sum, and avg ....................................................

for(I = 0; I<N; I++)
{
cout << "\nScore for bowler # " << I + 1 << " is  "  << score[I];

}
cout<<"\n\n The Sum is " << sum << "\n";
cout <<"\n The Average is "<< avg << "\n";


cout<<"\n\n\n";
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't match the problem description at all.

Comment: The problem asks for an array like this {1, 2, 3,.... 100}

Comment: Oh geez. I forgot to mention this code I put out is an earlier project thats suppose to be "similar" to it. But I thought it was a harder process then the answers below. Thank you for the tips. Im like a month into this. So I apologize for the terrible explanation.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/376c10d45012567b

Comment: Really? No one's even mentioned `std::iota` yet? That's what it's for.

Comment: You can delete it. I dont know how to explain this at all. The question is all it gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the code just needs to create the array, e.g. with

```
int arr[] = new int[100];
```

and then fill it in a for loop, e.g. with

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++) arr[i] = i+1;
```

Note that array indices count from zero, but you want to fill starting from one.

Comment: Thank you. Ive used arrays for a short period time and its confusing me lol. I bought the book "C++ for Business programmers" by John Molluzzo and am only on chapter 8 and some of the responses below are using functions I have not used yet. Yours seem to be the most legit. At least in my current state.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the code has something to do with your problem?

A sample program that does what you want is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100

int main(void)
{
        int arr[N], i;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                arr[i] = i + 1;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                printf("%d ", arr[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#define NUM_VALUES 100

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int array[NUM_VALUES];

    while (i <= NUM_VALUES)
    {
        array[i-1] = i;
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;

    while (i <= NUM_VALUES)
    {
        std::cout << array[i-1] << " ";
        i++;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```